# How to filter a column in Oracle Sql Developer with two matches

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am learning sqldeveloper slowly and I know how to filter based on a single matching string: just copy/paste the string you would like to match, or double click on it if you are lucky.

Now I would like to query based on two different strings, let's say 'ABC' or 'DEF', how would one do that in the 'Filter' option (right click on column) ?

[image: Complex filtering]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In fact the solution was simple, you need to use the 'Filter:' text box. Instead I was using the left click or right click + filter on a column.

So the solution was simply to put a SQL predicate in the text box:

references:

- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15846_01/doc.21/e15222/intro.htm#RPTUG10000
- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b31695/intro.htm#CHDHFJBE

[image: SQL predicate in Filter: text box]

Answer (score 4):

Using SQL Developer filter you can implement boolean expression like you can do in a Where clause.

For example:

**Filter: TASK_ID='100000001' OR TASK_ID='100000002'**